# error unsupported major.minor version 52.0 eclipse on MAC OS

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos, operating-system

How do I fix the error "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" using Eclipse on MAC OS 10.11 El Capitan when i export an apk?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'd a) switch to Android Studio since that's the currently supported Android development IDE while Eclipse is no longer b) check you Java version - that error means something can't work with a class compiled with Java 8. Most likely because you don't have java 8 installed / set as default jvm.

Comment: how do i change java version ??

Comment: Idk, I don't have a mac. Try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html

Answer (score 0):

Unsupported major.minor version related to `java -version`.

```
Java 8 = 52,
Java 7 = 51,
Java 6 = 50,
Java 5 = 49 and so on.
```

Please check your current java version and change it.

Comment: this is my version of java   java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: how do i change my java version on Mac i m new in OS ??